# Google's NearbyMessages API with only BLE Permissions is asking for Microphone Permission

Tags: android, google-nearby-messages

I want to use Google's Nearby Messages API to publish a simple message and I want to only use BLE for it so that [no Nearby Permissions dialog is required](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/user-consent#ble_only). I am creating my `MessagesClient` with just the `NearbyPermissions.BLE` flag:

```
private MessagesClient messagesClient(Context context) {
    return Nearby.getMessagesClient(context, messageOptions());
}

private MessagesOptions messageOptions() {
    return new MessagesOptions.Builder()
            .setPermissions(BLE)
            .build();
}

public void publish(Context context) {
    mMessagesClient = messagesClient(context);
    mMessagesClient
            .publish(mMessage) // publish without any PublishOptions
            .addOnSuccessListener( // ... )
}
```

I am purposedly not setting any `PublishOptions` object because [the documentation specifically states that the `Strategy.BLE` should only be used for subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/Strategy#public-static-final-strategy-ble_only) since it has an infinite TTL.  However, messages are failing with the following error message:

```
2807: Missing microphone permission
```

I tried reverse-engineering the API a little bit and creating a custom Strategy object for BLE with a default TTL, but I instead get a `2806: FORBIDDEN` error:

```
private PublishOptions publishOptions() {
    return new PublishOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(strategy())
            .build();
}

private Strategy strategy() {
    return new Strategy.Builder()
            .zze(2)
            .setTtlSeconds(TTL_SECONDS_DEFAULT)
            .build();
}
```

Why is the API requiring a microphone permission even when I've explicitly requested only BLE permissions? (fine location permissions are granted, by the way).

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have to broadcast and scan at the same time when you publish your message then modify your custom publish strategy by setting the discovery mode to “Strategy.DISCOVERY_MODE_BROADCAST”.

```
private Strategy strategy() {
    return new Strategy.Builder()
            .setDiscoveryMode(Strategy.DISCOVERY_MODE_BROADCAST)
            .setTtlSeconds(TTL_SECONDS_DEFAULT)
            .build();
}
```

This plus your BLE only client should permit publishing without microphone permissions.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Nearby Messages API Overview](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview):

> Nearby uses a combination of Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, Wi-Fi **and near-ultrasonic audio** to communicate a unique-in-time pairing code between devices.

So the API you are using is expecting to speak and listen with audio for nearby identification/messaging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Like I mentioned on my original question, I understand from the documentation that there is a BLE only mode, at least for subscriptions. I would expect this BLE only mode to also be available for publishing, unless the BLE only mode is only compatible with BLE beacons.